# how can I tell xalan NOT to validate XML retrieved using the "document" function?

Tags: java, xml, validation, xalan

Yesterday Oracle decided to take down java.sun.com for a while. This screwed things up for me because xalan tried to validate some XML but couldn't retrieve the properties.dtd.

I'm using xalan 2.7.1 to run some XSL transforms, and I don't want it to validate anything.
so tried loading up the XSL like this:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
spf.setValidating(false);
XMLReader rdr = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();      
Source xsl = new SAXSource(rdr, new InputSource(xslFilePath));  
Templates cachedXSLT  = factory.newTemplates(xsl);
Transformer transformer = cachedXSLT.newTransformer();         
transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

in the XSL itself, I do something like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="entry" select="document(concat($prefix, $locale_part, $suffix))/properties/entry[@key=$key]"/>
```

The XML this code retrieves has the following definition at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="...
```

Despite the java code above instructing the parser to NOT VALIDATE, it still sends a request to java.sun.com. While java.sun.com is unavailable, this makes the transform fail with the message:

```
 Can not load requested doc: http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd
```

How do I get xalan to stop trying to validate the XML loaded from the "document" function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation mentions that the parser may read the DTDs even if not validating, as it may become necessary to use the DTD to resolve (expand) entities.

Since I don't have control over the XML documents, [nont's option of modifying the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6616490/172211) was not available to me.

I managed to shut down attempts to pull in DTD documents by sabotaging the resolver, as follows.

My code uses a DocumentBuilder to return a Document (= DOM) but the XMLReader as per the OP's example also has a method `setEntityResolver` so the same technique should work with that.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false); // turns off validation
factory.setSchema(null);      // turns off use of schema
                              // but that's *still* not enough!
builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setEntityResolver(new NullEntityResolver()); // swap in a dummy resolver
return builder().parse(xmlFile);
```

Here, now, is my fake resolver: It returns an empty InputStream no matter what's asked of it.

```
/** my resolver that doesn't */
private static class NullEntityResolver implements EntityResolver {

    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) 
    throws SAXException, IOException {
        // Message only for debugging / if you care
        System.out.println("I'm asked to resolve: " + publicId + " / " + systemId);
        return new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));
    }

}
```

---

Alternatively, your fake resolver could return streams of actual documents read as local resources or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that disabling DTD loading will cause parsing to fail if the DTD defines any entities that your XML file depends on.  That said, to disable DTD loading try this, which assumes you're using the default Xerces that ships with Java.

```
    /*
     * Instantiate the SAXParser and set the features to prevent loading of an external DTD
     */
   SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
   XMLReader xrdr = sp.getXMLReader();
   xrdr.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
   xrdr.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

If you really need the DTD, then the other alternative is to implement a local XML catalog

```
    /*
     * Instantiate the SAXParser and add catalog support
     */
   SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
   XMLReader xrdr = sp.getXMLReader();

   CatalogResolver cr = new CatalogResolver();
   xrdr.setEntityResolver(cr);
```

To which you will have to provide the appropriate DTDs and an XML catalog definition.  This [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog) and [this article](http://xml.apache.org/commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html) were helpful.

CatalogResolver looks at the system property `xml.catalog.files` to determine what catalogs to load.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, it's not Xalan that's trying to do the DTD loading here, but Xerces.  This is happening long before Xalan gets its hands on the input stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the feature settings you recommend above, but I still get the failure from the attempt to download the DTD!

Comment: Are you using Xerces for parsing, or do you have another XML parser installed?

Comment: Are the parser's setting inherited when the XSL is executed? Because the document function is executed long after the XSL itself has been parsed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using xerces for parsing. At least I think I am. There's a xercesImpl.jar in tomcat's lib dir, and when I step through the code, the SAXParserFactory is instantiated as org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl. So I'm pretty confident that Xerces is in effect.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. The code I provided is taken from a class we currently use successfully to parse XML in environments that don't have an internet connection.  It might be instructive to intercept the network traffic with Wireshark to see what's really being requested... it might be something else.

Comment: The code parses the xsl just fine. It's when we execute the transform that it makes the request. I might just resort to changing the host file to point java.sun.com to localhost and serve the Dtd from there.

Comment: It's not just entities you lose if you suppress the DTD/schema. There could be default values, and your XSL processing could be incorrect without them. For example stuff element could be defined to have a default value of "great" for attribute type. When your xsl does something with stuff/@type on a document that has simply <stuff>, the value will be "great" if the DTD has been loaded, and empty otherwise. So your XSL could run incorrectly. Of course assuming you know your DTD or schema, you could make yourself aware of any defaults and code around it, but this is a mistake waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try using setFeature on `SAXParserFactory`.

Try this:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setValidating(false);
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

I think that should be enough, otherwise try setting a few other features:

```
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
spf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
```

Comment: Just tried this too, no luck! I'm starting to wonder if the parser settings apply to the XSL that we parse, but not documents read by the XSL using the document function?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up stripping the doctype declaration out of the XML, because nothing else worked. When I get around to it, I'll try this: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/UseCatalog.html#UsingCatsXalan

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting, but I have found a solution which actually works and decided I should share it.

**1.**
For some reason, setValidating(false) doesn't work. In some cases, it still downloads external DTD files. To prevent this, you should attach a custom EntityResolver as advised [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.xml.sax.XMLReader&method=setEntityResolver):

```
XMLReader rdr = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();      
rdr.setEntityResolver(new MyCustomEntityResolver());
```

The EntityResolver will be called for every external entity request. Returning **null** will not work because the framework will still download the file from the Internet after that. Instead, you can return an empty stream which is a valid DTD, as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27962998/680327):

```
private class MyCustomEntityResolver implements EntityResolver {
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
        return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
    }
}
```

**2.**
You are telling setValidating(false) to the SAX parser which reads your XSLT code. That is, it will not validate your XSLT. When it encounters a document() function, it loads the linked XML file using another parser which still validates it, and also downloads external entities. To handle this, you should attach a custom URIResolver to the transformer:

```
Transformer transformer = cachedXSLT.newTransformer();
transformer.setURIResolver(new MyCustomURIResolver());
```

The transformer will call your URIResolver implementation when it encounters the document() function. Your implementation will have to return a Source for the passed URI. The simplest thing is to return a StreamSource as advised [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/126266/XML/XSLT-document-function-error). But in your case you should parse the document yourself, preventing validation and external requests using the customized SAXParser you already have (or create a new one each time).

```
private class MyCustomURIResolver implements URIResolver {
    public Source resolve(String href, String base) {
        return new SAXSource(rdr,new InputSource(href));
    }
}
```

So you will have to implement two custom interfaces in your code.